# Caption on top of Figure with revTex 4.1 after update to Tex Live 2014

Tags: floats

I used this kind of code to put several Figures in a Latex document

```
\documentclass[preprint]{revtex4-1}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[!h]
  \begin{center}
    \begin{tabular}{c}
      \resizebox{0.5\linewidth}{!}{\includegraphics{image1}}
      \resizebox{0.5\linewidth}{!}{\includegraphics{image2}}\\
      \resizebox{0.5\linewidth}{!}{ \includegraphics{image3}}
      \resizebox{0.5\linewidth}{!}{ \includegraphics{image4}}\\
   \end{tabular}
   \caption{Here is the caption of my figure.}
   \label{fig:figure1}
  \end{center}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

and I compile with `latex` and `dvipdfmx`.

My images are the following
http://heberg-fichiers.informatique13.com/uploads/c21bea2965.eps,
http://heberg-fichiers.informatique13.com/uploads/3241c8d389.eps,
http://heberg-fichiers.informatique13.com/uploads/e30b2e3f5e.eps,
http://heberg-fichiers.informatique13.com/uploads/6700fd0f83.eps,

It was working perfectly until I update from Tex Live 2009 to TeX Live 2014. Now some parts of the caption are on top of the Figure.

Comment: Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: It is hard to believe, that the behaviour of `\caption` command should change completely from 2009 to 2014. Are you using `\caption` package? Is there some `\captionsetup` command?

Comment: Thanks for the remark. It is in fact due to the class `\documentclass[preprint]{revtex4-1}`, but again it was not behaving like this in the previous version of Tex. I edit my question

Comment: How do you compile?

Comment: Why don't you use `pdflatex`? It will automatically convert the EPS files to PDF. I've seen other problems of `dvipdfmx` with some EPS files.

Comment: In case readers have other `TeX` systems: the automatic conversion of EPS to PDF by `pdflatex` is relatively new (in `TeX Live` I think it was added in 2013, maybe 2012). It depends on shell-escape capabilities to call some version of `epstopdf` to perform the conversion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't see any problem with this code if I do either of the following: (1) run `latex` and then `dvips` and then `ps2pdf`; or (2) convert the `eps` figures to `pdf` (with `epstopdf`) and then run pdflatex.

I *do* see the problem described when running first latex and then `dvipdfm`, but that is a rather unnatural way to process a file with a lot of `eps` figures.

Comment: Thank you, I do not remember why I was using the `dvipdfmx` (more or less 5 years I have been using it) but it is alright with `latex` and then `dvips` and then `ps2pdf`.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to compile with `dvipdfmx`, then you should explicitly pass the option to `graphicx`; without it, the behavior is indeed like you describe, and it is caused by `graphicx` believing that the `dvips` driver is desired.

```
\documentclass[preprint]{revtex4-1}
\usepackage[dvipdfmx]{graphicx}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[htp]
\centering
\includegraphics[width=.45\linewidth]{image1}\hfil
\includegraphics[width=.45\linewidth]{image2}\\
\includegraphics[width=.45\linewidth]{image3}\hfil
\includegraphics[width=.45\linewidth]{image4}

\caption{Here is the caption of my figure.}
\label{fig:figure1}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

I have also simplified the input: the `tabular` is not necessary and also `\resizebox`.

[image]

However, if you don't need `dvipdfmx` for other reasons, you can simply remove the `dvipdfmx` option and process the file with `pdflatex`, that will automatically convert the EPS files to PDF.

Comment: It is working, but since I have a lot of this kind of Figure and I need to change the code, I prefer the second option. Thank you

Comment: @lambertmular You *don't* need to change the code. The only required action is using `\usepackage[dvipdfmx]{graphicx}` instead of `\usepackage{graphicx}`. The code you use for placing the images is not the best, though.